# tileMode="repeat" broken on Android 4.1 jelly bean

Tags: android, drawable, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My app uses tiled backgrounds in a couple of places, and when I tested in the Android 4.1 Jelly Bean emulator, these backgrounds simply don't show up.  I tried putting a regular image in instead, and it shows up fine.  So I'm wondering if the tileMode="repeat" had been deprecated or something?  Though I can't find any information saying so online.  Here's my background xml file:

backrepeat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/greenchecker" 
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

And here is where I use it in my button:

greenchecker_btn.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat_over" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeat" />

</selector>
```

Anyone got any idea why this has stopped working in 4.1?  Works in all other versions as far as I know.
Thanks!

EDIT -

Seem to have solved the problem by replacing the tiling files which were gifs, with pngs.

Comment: not sure , but try what they show here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=2jCVmfCse1E#t=923s . sadly i don't have a JB device so i can't know if anything would help you . try to read and watch other google articles and videos .

Comment: Hmm.  Just replaced the gifs I was using with pngs and they now show up fine.  Maybe a gif issue in the end.

Comment: odd . please put your answer and mark it as answered so that others won't need to see it as un-answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to have solved the problem by replacing the tiling files which were gifs, with pngs.

Comment: Thanks, was searching everywhere guess its pngs not gifs from now on